# Does not getting a pay raise signal for something to come...?

Tags: communication, salary, new-job, performance-reviews

So I've had a talk with my manager and lead and they determined I wasn't getting a pay raise due to communication. My current job is remote and so as my manager and lead. During my review, they've stated I'm not calling/communicating with them enough. They seem to be very A type personality and I'm not the type of person to just ring up my manager on a Saturday to talk about my personal life. (my manager has does to be by the way) I try to keep professional and separate my work life and personal life.

I do however call them if something urgent comes up and do talk with them during our project meetings and explain issues and give suggestions. I have multiple projects going and has been very hectic (60hr weeks for months) As a result, they've said I don't qualify for a raise. This really has never been an issue with my previous companies and I've been with this company for a little over a year. Is this a sign of things to come?

Comment: Please be a bit more explicit about what you are worried about. Also, you don't qualify for a raise because you have multiple projects?

Comment: What do they mean by not communicating? Having been a remote worker in a team that wasn't remotely friendly, I would err on the side of over communicating. Also take the time to ask other people how they're doing. You don't have to get onto personal topics, but such as how is the weather, did they do anything fun on the weekend, and things like that.

Comment: If you have been working 60 hour weeks for months and they have denied you a raise, you should nope the heck out of there as soon as you can find another job.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill How do we know they are not already getting paid an appropriate rate? Maybe in those 60 hours they are only doing a standard week's worth of work?

Comment: (my manager has does to be by the way) - Can you fix this?

Answer (score 10):

**Side-answer**

"60hr weeks for months" and you still work there?!

Man, that is the biggest signal that you need to update and then use your CV. That is exploitation. And since you do not get a salary raise, I assume you do not get paid for the 50% extra-work either.

*This is not a sign of the things to come, it is a proof of the things that already Are!!*

**Main Answer**

There are bosses like the one(s) you described, which value you talking to them more than you doing real work. I know this from experience. I was shocked 2 times in the past because of this:

1. Why for many years I did not get the raises and the recognition that I deserved (actually, more than deserved)?
2. Why did I started to get a lot of recognition after I started reporting to my (relevant) boss(es), even though my amount of work declined significantly? It was senior level work, true, but still, the levels of stress were through the floor compared to before.

**Simple solution: give your bosses *what they expect*, not what you think they need.**

Comment: I'm also traveling 60% of time which includes working Saturdays/Sundays........maybe it's time I rethink my role.

Comment: If you like to travel, then it can be OK to continue. If it is just boring commute, then I agree, you should rethink your options.

Answer (score 2):

Does not getting a raise is a signal of something? 
*Indifferently.*

Does not getting a raise AND working 60hr weeks for months IS a signal of something? 
**Yes it is.**
They will squeeze you like a lemon for the most work you can do for the lowest amount of money.

Is communication part of your job? Was is in your yearly goals?

Did you had task named "communication"?

It show that they just don't want to pay you and use some trivial excuse.

What is "enough communication"? Monthly written reports? Daily verbal ones? 
Records of key pressed during a week and mile travelled by mouse?

It cannot be surprise rule showed at review. If your boss felt you don't communicate enough they should let you know **when it was happening** not wait for review to cite it as a reason for not giving you a rise.

Answer (score 1):

> During my review, they've stated I'm not calling/communicating with
>   them enough.
>
> I have multiple projects going and has been very hectic (60hr weeks
>   for months) As a result, they've said I don't qualify for a raise.
>   This really has never been an issue with my previous companies and
>   I've been with this company for a little over a year. Is this a sign
>   of things to come?

Possibly.

If your lack of communication is such that they won't give you a raise, then you may not be cut out for this role unless you can change.

Often working remotely means it is more difficult to stay in touch with others. Work harder to learn how your lead and manager expect you to communicate and then follow through.

Make sure you understand specifically what they mean regarding calling/communication. It may have nothing to do with calling on Saturday and instead may mean that they want you to contact them when you are stuck, for example.

If this is your first indication that your communication is insufficient, then you may be able to salvage things. If you were already warned and still this was the reason cited during your salary review for not getting a raise, then you may want to start polishing your resume.